# SVN: how to lock a file so that no one can modifiy it?

Tags: locking, tortoisesvn

We are using TortoiseSVN for a project. One file in this project has a special status. It can be modified locally but the SVN version must not be modified.

So, I have locked the file so that noone, unless me, can modify this file. Now I am searching a way so that even me cannot modify this file. Do you know if it is possible and how?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a serverside pre-commit hook that rejects commits touching that file.

See http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

There is an example function listing all affected files.  To make the script reject the commit, write "You cannot modify THENAMEOFTHEFILE" to STDERR and exit with an error code.  For example `sys.stderr.write("ProjectThingyFile.txt is read-only.\n"); sys.exit(1)`

Comment: Thanks. I will see with the server admin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be part of the SVN repository as you can **ignore** it so it will not be committed and can remain unique per users machine.

Find the file right click on it
goto the tortoiseSVN Menu
Unversion and add to ignore list or add to ignore list

This process will stop any changes to that file being committed from any user

[Tortoise SVN Documentation on this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

Hope this helps

Jason

Comment: Yes. It needs to be committed. Content is required for the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy user that no one logs in as and have that user lock the file instead of yourself.